# Setup TFS/Test Manager to send email on test failure

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-sdk

Is it possible to setup TFS/Test Manager so that it sends out an email after a test fails?

Comment: Are you failing a build or creating a bug workitem when the test fails?

Comment: Currently, nothing happens when a test fails. We'd like to have an email sent out to the test owner, when a test fails.

Comment: What kind of tests, and what is running them? eg Unit, Automated or Manual, running as part of the build or in test manager?

Comment: Automated unit tests, they run as part of the build and from test manager as well.

Comment: doesn't it make more sense to send an email to the person who broke the build than the person who owns the test?

Comment: @Betty We have separate build and test systems. So if someone breaks the build they already get the notification. We want the test server to be able to notify the testers if his/her test failed as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but it requires quite a lot of changes/additions to the process template and possibly a custom-made activity.

1. After tests have run, we check if `BuildDetail.BuildPhaseStatus` has status `failed`
2. We send mail to everyone who has changesets committed to this build, so the build goes through `BuildDetail.AssociatedChangesets` (you need to have `AssociateChangesetsAndWorkItems` on) and get the committer username.
3. Unfortunately for us, there's no good correlation between TFS username and email address at our place, so we had to create a custom activity that looks that up in the AD.
4. The actual email is sent with the `BuildReport` action from Community TFS Build Extensions. We modified the xslt, but that's not really necessary. We also wanted to include a listing of the failed tests, and that required modification of the action itself (test data isn't included by default).

Looking at this description and all the work made to get this working, I'm beginning to wonder if it was worth it ;).